# Connect to a FTPS - Cannot find the requested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, tls1.2, filezilla

I am trying to connect to local FTPS (FileZilla Server) with a certificate and no password with a local Certificate (crt)

When I test the connection with FileZilla Client, it works.

But when I am trying to connect through a webapp in ASP.NET like this.

```
System.Net.Security.SslStream stream = new System.Net.Security.SslStream(this.tcpClient.GetStream());
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate("C:\\MyLocal\\Certificate\\mycert.crt");
stream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
```

I always get the exception **Cannot find the requested object.\r\n** on the second line.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

When I try to install my certificate I get the Windows message:

**This file is invalid for use as the following: Security Certificate**

I can find many articles in Google, but with no resolution.

Comment: Did you double check the path of the certificate and its permissions?

Comment: The path is ok. I tried to run the certificate to install it in the Certificate Store, but I get: This file is invalid for use as the following: Security Certificate. How can I check its permissions? I created to test it which works with FZ client.